# I need to send event to the instance after fetching. Javascript Class

Tags: javascript

I want to call a function from a method. I don't even know how to ask correctly. test.onload() is called immediately, not after 3 seconds. See code for example, please.

```
export default class {
  constructor() {
    // some code
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.onload;
    }, 3000);
  }

  onload = (fn) => {
    console.log('loaded event');
    fn();
  };
}
```

```
const test = new TEST();

test.onload(function () {
  console.log('from instance');
});
```

Comment: This code seems to have multiple errors. First you need to name your class. I assume you named it `TEST` ? Then obviously you are passing a callback method as a parameter to `onload`. This method is not provided inside of the `setTimeout`. And then I dont get why you are calling `onload` manually after instantiating the class. The call should be made 3s after instantiating the class autmatically since you defined the timeout in the constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling the function directly. Somehow you think that will be called when the setTimeout runs which is not the case.

If you want the function "from instance" to be called you need to rethink how you are registering it. You are going to have to store the function somehow and let the timer pick it up and execute it.

Setting it with the constructor

```js
class TEST {
  constructor(callback) {
    this.callback = callback;
    setTimeout(() => this.onload(), 3000);
  }

  onload = () => {
    console.log('loaded event');
    if(this.callback) this.callback();
  };
}

const test = new TEST(function () {
  console.log('from instance');
});
```

Setting it with a method

```js
class TEST {
  constructor() {
    setTimeout(() => this.onload(), 3000);
  }

  onload = () => {
    console.log('loaded event');
    if(this.callback) this.callback();
  };
  
  registerCallback(callback) {
    this.callback = callback;
  }
}

const test = new TEST();
test.registerCallback(function () {
  console.log('from instance');
});
```